# for NullPointerException

Tags: android

> 10-15 17:12:24.365 1102-1102/com.example.nurkan.iip E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                             at com.example.nurkan.iip.Adapter.DAdapter.getItemCount(DAdapter.java:61)

```
public class DAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {


Activity activity;

private List<Dannye> heroes;

public DAdapter(Activity activity, List<Dannye> heroes) {
    this.heroes = heroes;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_dannye, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Dannye dannye = heroes.get(position);
    holder.bind(dannye);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return heroes.size();
}


public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView hour;
    private TextView urok;
    private TextView spes;
    private TextView aut;


    private RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        hour = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TWhour);
        urok = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TWlesson);
        spes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TWspes);
        aut = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TWaut);
    }

    public void bind(Dannye heroModel) {
        hour.setText(heroModel.hour);
        urok.setText(heroModel.lesson);
        spes.setText(heroModel.spes);
        aut.setText(heroModel.aut);
    }
}
```

}

//проблема в

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return heroes.size();
}
```

Comment: I believe the error is not in this code...
Don´t you have a method named getItemCount at your adapter? Check the line 61 - the nullpointer is there I think.

com.example.nurkan.iip.Adapter.DAdapter.getItemCount(DAdapter.java:61)

Comment: На этом сайте мы пишем только на английском

Comment: Please post the exact code at line 61 in your `DAdapter.java` file

Comment: @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return heroes.size();
}

Comment: @Nurkan `heroes` is null

Comment: @Nurkan You removed the code you posted earlier where you initialize your array (read form dist and serialize). Your problem is there. Post that code as well so we can help you.

Answer (score -2):

Your `heroes` array is `null`.  The code you are using to instantiate isn't working correctly.